# Android 4.0 EditText cursor is always invisible for editable=false

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, text-cursor

In my app I want an `EditText` that doesn't accept any input, i.e. `android:editable="false"` in XML layout or `setKeyListener(null)` in code.

I only want to add characters in a very controlled manner, and so I always add it programmatically with `setText()` and I don't want any virtual keyboard to show up. However, I still need a visible cursor in the `EditText` so that the user will know where the programmatic input will be inserted.

This was very easy to implement (`android:editable="false"`) until Android 4.0. In 4.0, the cursor was apparently removed. I've tried `android:cursorVisible="true"` but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to both have a visible cursor and still suppress input in Android 4.0? Really grateful for any help here.

Comment: Actually, I found that the solution below was working on the emulator, but when I later tested on device, the keyboard would still appear when clicking inside the EditText.Another solution (specific to Android 4.0 and above) that seems to work on device as well is given here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be almost what I'm looking for, except that the EditText is still editable and therefore accepts input from hardware keyboard buttons even though the virtual keyboard is suppressed. I guess I can solve that by filtering its input though. Thanks @Maurycy

Answer (score 2):

Set android:focusable=false in your EditText.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but focusable=false unfortunately doesn't give me any cursor in the EditText

Comment: focusable is mostly for like trackball and keyboard navigating around  the view

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Try using:

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

it worked for me. For more details see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27609